# html table export to excel formula in excel file not working after export, other cell add number working fine

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I have code below for data export from HTML table into Excel file. My question is, after file export when user adds formula to excel for calculation's, Excel formula is not working. When I add 2 and 2 to other cell formula working fine. But exported data cell formula is not working. I checked in Excel file cell formats is general or number

In the example below `=SUM(D2,D3)` is not working.

```
function ExportoExcel() {
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j = 0;
    tab = document.getElementById('printtable'); // id of table

    for (j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) {
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus();
        sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    }
    else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

    return (sa);
}
```

[image: image where example]

Comment: I can reproduce this problem by adding no-break-spaces &nbsp; as the first character inside the tr tags. In excel the figures align left with a space like yours but add up to zero.